# PickerView is not showing

Tags: ios, storyboard, textfield

I'm trying to bring up a picker view instead of a keyboard to put in a textfield, but my picker view doesn't show.

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "FindClasses.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *classTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FindClasses *finder;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *itemsArray;
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *itemsArray = [self.finder findClassesInTimetable];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)presentPicker {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);
    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    // TODO: animate this on screen
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self presentPicker];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.itemsArray count];  //where items is your array of items
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I took the example from another Stackoverflow post:

Comment: `CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);` what is this?? you have to set its width & height

Comment: Have you set the `UITextField`s `inputView` as your `pickerView`?

Comment: @MohitPopat oops, corrected this.

Comment: did it work? may i put as answer?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer How would I do this? Just self.textField.inputView = picker;?

Comment: I have posted sample code for a working model of what your're looking for.

Comment: @user3347446 just check you have set TextField's Delegate or not? if not then set and just set pickerview's width & height as i said in first comment. it will work

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you

```
 - (void)presentPicker {
        UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.dataSource = self;
        // TODO: animate this on screen
        classTextField .delegate = self;
        classTextField.inputView = picker;
    }

 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  {
       [textField becomeFirstResponder];
       return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `[self.view addSubview:picker];`. And change delegate method to `textFieldShouldBeginEditing'.

Answer (score 1):

This is how **I** use `UIPickerView`s, with sample code:

```
UIPickerView* genderPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

genderPicker.delegate = self;

genderPicker.dataSource = self;
```

After initializing your `UITextField` (registrationGenderField in my case):

```
registrationGenderField.inputView = genderPicker;
```

And then the `delegate`s and `dataSource`s:

```
- (NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
          titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
         forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

switch (row) {

        case 0:
            return @"Gender";
            break;

        case 1:
            return @"Male";
            break;

        case 2:
            return @"Female";
            break;

        default:
            return @"Gender";
            break;
    }
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    switch (row) {

        case 0:
            registrationGenderField.text = @"";
            break;

        case 1:
            registrationGenderField.text =  @"Male";
            break;

        case 2:
            registrationGenderField.text =  @"Female";
            break;

        default:
            registrationGenderField.text =  @"";
            break;
    }
}



- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to alloc init your pickerview;

and set its delegate to self and also add uipickerviewdelegate and datasource in .h file

than in textfieldbegin editing add [textField setInputView:picker];

also implement textfieldshouldreturn